# Wi-fi wont turn on after root. Not even with factory reset!!! please help me

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, factory-reset, hard-reset

so, my phone went completely bananas today. It was charging and i swear out of the blue a messange showed up saying the sd card memory was being deleted. So in panick i turned it off.
The cellphone then turned itself on and showed a message saying android was being deleted, again in panick i took the battery off.
When i turned it on, a message with a "dead" android avatar showed on the screen and the boot options screen showed up. I clicked on reeboot and it had been reseted to factory settings. 
I was so angry and upset because my whole life and work was on my phone.
I spent the entire afternoon dedicated into recovering the data. The only software that seems to find my files costed $50. i live in a 3rd world country so thats impossible for me to pay. Then looking online i found another one that seem promising but i had to root my phone for it. in the past i used to be really afraid of doing it but as i had an old phone i rooted once for some trivial stuff i decided to do it.
Big mistake.
After rooting my  wi-fi turned off...for good.
When i click the wi-fi switch it turns on for a  aplit of a second and back off.
i CANNOT turn it on.
So i decided to hard reset it again, i mean, i had nothing to lose.
NOTHING.
I STILL CANT TURN IT ON.

i really need this phone for work, and i do not have money to get a new one. im desesperate. really.
i reaaly hope someone can help
I understand so little about this but im great at following intructions. I will be so thankfull if anyone can help.

its a samsung Galaxy J5, with android 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you have nothing left on your device, you can try re-flashing the stock ROM by downloading the flash file and flashing it via Odin. It should reinstall the corrupted modem drivers and system files.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have no idea what that means, but im guessing Mr. google knows :)